# Formatting of an antlr file

Tags: parsing, antlr, antlr4

I know that this 'type of question' is a bit frowned on on StackOverflow, but I think it hopefully has a good intent and can be answered in a meaningfully way to help with coding in ANTLR.

I usually see -- and also have adopted -- the standard formatting using by most `g4` grammars, which looks something like this:

```
id
    : something
    | something-else
    ...
    ;
```

This works fine and is nicely readable for highly nested items and I get why it's used. However, a lot of times I'll scroll through hundreds of lines of code to understand lexer rules that are much like this:

```
MINUS
   : '-'
   ;


TIMES
   : '*'
   ;


DIV
   : '/'
   ;


GT
   : '>'
   ;


LT
   : '<'
   ;


EQ
   : '='
   ;


POINT
   : '.'
   ;


POW
   : '^'
   ;
```

In a way, I find it quite hard to read and to keep track of, as I'm often scrolling back and forth just to see what related tokens mean. Is there any disadvantage of using formatting such as the following for lexing tokens where there is almost zero complexity or alternation used?

```
MINUS  :  '-';
TIMES  :  '*';
DIV    :  '/';
GT     :  '>';
LT     :  '<';
EQ     :  '=';
POINT  :  '.';
POW    :  '^';
```

Comment: I know of no downside.  (And prefer the latter for being more concise).  You may also be seeing the results of some code formatter acting on the source.

Comment: Formatting is personal. I prefer one line for one rule, parser rules alphabetically sorted, because it is easy to read and find rules. And you might want to employ a naming convention to remind you of keywords vs punctuation in lexer rules. But sometimes an IDE that has a language server for Antlr is the best way to navigate around the grammar.

Comment: @kaby76 thanks that sounds like a real clean way to format it. Do you have any sample files, even a dozen lines or so with a format that you've used before?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/antlr/grammars-v4/blob/master/dart2/Dart2Parser.g4. It is  a grammar generated from a spec.

Comment: @kaby76 nice and neat and concise! Didn't have to scroll over 1,000 lines just to see the definitions. Thanks for sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting is indeed a matter of taste (I for one consider colon and semicolon as block delimiters and hence put them like you would place parentheses in source code). However, grammar rules can differ greatly, both in size and in complexity. So, there's no one-fits-all formatting approach and it's totally fine to use multiple lines for large/complex rules and single line for short rules (or blocks).

I have considered these aspects in my [ANTLR4 grammar formatter](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/doc/formatting.md) which comes with a [large list of options](https://github.com/mike-lischke/vscode-antlr4/blob/master/doc/extension-settings.md#grammar-formatting) to configure how you would like to see your grammar, like break-before-parentheses, hanging-semicolon and min-empty-lines (to name just a few). This formatter is part of the [ANTLR4 extension for VS Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=mike-lischke.vscode-antlr4).